# two functions are occurring at the same time

Tags: c, visual-studio

I have to create a program that creates a guess the letter game.
Everything is built successfully. However, I run into a problem because the GetTheLetter function and the CompareThe Letters function are combining and printing at the same time. When it prompts the user for a guess, it is also printing out the first if statement of the CompareTheLetters function. What am I doing wrong?

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#define MAXGUESSES 4
#include <stdio.h>

void GuessItRules(); //Game instructions
int PlayOneGame(char letter); //Runs a game
char GetTheLetter(); //Prompts user to guess and returns guess
int IsAWinner(char letter, char userguess); //Returns either a 1 or a 0 depending on if the user guessed correctly
void CompareTheLetters(char letter, char userguess); //Prints message dependent on whether guess comes before, after, or is the letter


int main()
{
    //declare additional variables
    //declare FILE pointer
    FILE* PTR;

    int numOfgames; //number of games user wants to play
    int i;      //iterator

    char letter;    //letter from file
    int win;    //variable for the return of the PlayOneGame function

    //display instructions
    GuessItRules();
    //connect to the file HINT: use fopen
    PTR = fopen("letters.txt", "r");
    //get number of games to play
    printf("Let's start playing!\n\nHow many games would you like to play (1-5)?\n\n");
    scanf("%d", &numOfgames);
    //this for loop will allow the player to play more than one game
    //without recompiling
    for (i = 0; i < numOfgames; i++)
    {
        //get a letter from file - use fscanf
        fscanf(PTR, "%c", &letter);

        //Play one game (Call PlayOneGame function) - remember the function has an int return type
        win = PlayOneGame(letter);
        //tell the player if they have won or lost (test the variable win)      
        if (win == 1)
            printf("Congrats! You guessed the correct letter!!\n\n");
        else if (win == 0)
            printf("I'm sorry you did not guess the correct answer :( The letter was %c\n\n", letter);
    }

    //close file 
    fclose(PTR);
    return 0;
}

//Function definitions

void GuessItRules()
{
    printf("Welcome to the Guess the Letter Game!\n-------------------------------------\n\n");
    printf("You will have 4 chances to guess the letter per a game\n\n");
}

int PlayOneGame(char letter)
{
    int numOfguesses = 0;
    int winOrLose = 0;  //should be intialized
    char userguess;     // user guess

    //As long as the user  has not used up the maximum number
    //of guesses and has not guessed correctly 
    //the game will continue using this while loop
    while (numOfguesses < MAXGUESSES && winOrLose == 0)
    {

        //function call to GetTheletter - returns to userguess variable
        userguess = GetTheLetter();
        //function call to IsAWinner - returns to winOrLose variable (0 or 1)
        winOrLose = IsAWinner(letter, userguess);
        //function call to CompareTheLetters - gives the user a message
        CompareTheLetters(letter, userguess);
        //update counter for number of guesses used
        numOfguesses = numOfguesses + 1;
    }

    return winOrLose;  //(0 or 1)
}

char GetTheLetter()
{
    char userguess;
    printf("Please enter a guess \n\n");
    scanf("%c", &userguess);
    return (userguess);
}

int IsAWinner(char letter, char userguess)
{
    if (userguess == letter)
        return (1);
    else
        return (0);
}

void CompareTheLetters(char letter, char userguess)
{
    if (userguess < letter)
    {
        printf("The letter you are trying to guess comes after %c\n\n", userguess);
    }
    else if (userguess > letter)
    {
        printf("The letter you are trying to guess comes before %c\n\n", userguess);
    }
    else if (userguess == letter)
    {
        printf("The letter is %c!!!!\n\n", userguess);
        printf("Congrats!!! You did it!!\n\n");
    }

}
```

Comment: "are combining and printing at the same time". What exactly do you mean by that? Please update the question to show  the exact input and output.

Comment: Is there a canonical 'newline left in buffer' question?  There are, like several of these a day, now:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in when you ask the user for a letter to guess.

When you use the `%c` format specifier to `scanf`, a newline satisfies this format specifier.  Since there will have been a newline left in the input buffer from your previous input, this picks up that newline.

Put a space at the beginning of the format string to absorb the newline:

```
scanf(" %c", &userguess);
```

Note that other format specifiers such as `%d` and `%f` will skip over newlines, unlike `%c`.  So the leading space to skip newlines is needed *only* for `%c`.

Comment: yes, I figured it out. That was the exact problem. I also had to do that for the scanf(" %c", &letter);